# How to prevent error with counter in procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure which I use for a while now. I works fine but it shows me also an error after completion.
Here's the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `import_U_P`()
BEGIN

DECLARE anzahl INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE zaehler INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM help_import_U_P INTO anzahl;
SET zaehler = 0;
WHILE zaehler < anzahl DO
  
-- Einfügen der Felder in Personen
INSERT INTO eitw_Personen(PersID, P_Aktiv)
    SELECT PersID, P_Aktiv
    FROM help_import_U_P WHERE P_bekannt NOT LIKE "%Y%"; 
    
SET zaehler = zaehler + 1;
END WHILE;

END;
```

and this is the error I get:

`Query 1 ERROR at Line 1: : Duplicate entry '23785' for key 'eitw_personen.PRIMARY'`

where 23785 is die ID of the first record I am inserting with the procedure.
I guess it is a problem with the counter, like he counts one too much - therefore I tried to set `zaehler = 1` and also on the other side: `WHILE zaehler < anzahl-1 DO`. but I always get the same error. Now I am running out of ideas. Anybody knows how to prevent the error?

Cheers
Ralf

Comment: `SELECT PersID, P_Aktiv FROM help_import_U_P WHERE P_bekannt NOT LIKE "%Y%"` is always return the same data irrespective of `zaehler` and `anzahl` value.

Comment: every time you run through the loop you are inserting by selecting the same records What is it you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to achieve that all records in help_import_U_P are inserted in eitw_Personen. That is working well because I am working with the procedure for a while now. 
I think that SET zaehler = zaehler + 1; raises up the counter for the records. 
My problem is not that the procedure's not working but the error message that is shown when the procedure is (successfully) finished.

Comment: ??you aren't using zaehler in the insert so I don't believe it has been working. anyway please add table definitions, sample data and expected outcome as text,

Comment: Here's what your code does without a primary key - is this as intended?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/P3I23DBC

Comment: The procedure really is just trying to reinsert the same data over and over. `SELECT PersID, P_Aktiv
    FROM help_import_U_P WHERE P_bekannt NOT LIKE "%Y%";` is going to be running `N times` which is equal to  anzahl. You could basically have the loop removed, it would make the SP simpler and you would achieve your goal

Comment: Check this out https://dbfiddle.uk/6CUyV-dh

Comment: wow, interesting! Thanks for your efforts so far! So the error message is caused by the attempt to enter the block of data into eitw_Personen for the second time because P_ID is the primary key and does not accept doubles. 
For someone who's just getting into MySQL: so there would be 2 versions to get this data in eitw_Personen: 1) by looping and 2) by block. Which is the "cleaner" version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `WHILE` loop to copy a set of rows. If the `SELECT` matches all the rows you need, it will insert that set of rows in one statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `import_U_P`()
BEGIN

INSERT INTO eitw_Personen(PersID, P_Aktiv)
    SELECT PersID, P_Aktiv
    FROM help_import_U_P WHERE P_bekannt NOT LIKE '%Y%'; 
    
END
```